# How to remove the extra space between label and input?

Tags: html, css

There is a side bar with a couple of labels and input. I want to remove the space between a pair of label and input. How to remove the space?
[Space between label and input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gefsT.png).

Here is the main part of html

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

aside#sidebar-wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

aside#sidebar-wrapper input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <h1>Get A Quote</h1>
    <form action="" class="form-sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-input-wrapper">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-input-wrapper">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="button_1">Send</button>
    </form>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the element inspector in your browser's devtools to see that margin and/or padding are causing this. But basically setting the margin and padding of these elements to 0 should do the trick, I think..

Comment: As you can see there is none, or close to none in the runnable snippet @j08691 kindly edited in your question. That means that you have a style somewhere else that is affecting this, or you are missing something like a normalizer or reset CSS and are on a speciifc browser. Without further details, [the tips in the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343362/how-to-remove-the-extra-space-between-label-and-input#comment112008001_63343362) are the best anyone could provide.

Comment: Got it! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to tackle this issue is by setting margin or padding to the two elements.
I would advise you to set padding & margin 0 for both label and input and if you still want to reduce the gap, sometimes you will probably need to set a negative margin which is not recommended but still does the job.
try this on your label

```
.label {
   /*margin-bottom: -5px;*/
    margin-bottom: 0px
  }
```

In HTML

```
<label class="lable">...</label>
```

Again, this practice of adding a negative margin is highly discouraged.

EDIT: I missed the display:inline-block property, which someone in comments reminded me of
Above fix won't work, Making margin-bottom: 0 for the label will work though
a js fiddle:

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

aside#sidebar-wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

aside#sidebar-wrapper input {
  width: 100%;
}


.lable {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <h1>Get A Quote</h1>
    <form action="" class="form-sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-input-wrapper">
        <label class="lable">Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="nameINput">
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-input-wrapper">
        <label class="lable">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="button_1">Send</button>
    </form>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Both label and input are `display: inline`, per default, so margin and padding bottom or top should not affect them.

Comment: Yes, I realised it now, thanks for informing. I am stuck to margin: 0 approach now

Comment: @AmodShinde you most likely has other css affecting your elements, it will be easy to spot if you inspect element. It's always important to know why the issue occurred, more important than the fix itself

Comment: I agree to it, just a small piece of css code cant guarantee the fix something. but unfortunately, I cant comment on the post because my points are less and at the same time cant post an answer with 2-3 lines, so had to elaborate.
using browser dev tools is always must

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is caused by... New line in the code. That is new line between `label` and `input`. I am not sure why exactly this new line is being displayed, but I've encountered similar behavior even when the are in different order, when it can be rendered as space.
In fact, even in the snippet, if you try selecting the label text and then move your mouse slightly down to where that "extra space" is you will see how selection increases by 1 character of "nothing".
I thought I was seeing things, but https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements-in-css.php actually suggests removing those new lines to remove the extra space in the 1st method shown on page.
So... I guess we should just be careful with extra new lines in our code. Or use `flex` on parent as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ suggest (`font-size: 0` does not always work for me)

Answer (score -1):

If you have no margin or padding applied and you still have this space, you could either use `display: flex` on the parent or `display: block/inline-block` on the label to get rid of these.

Comment: Why use flex when it is totally unnecessary

Comment: Because it is an effective way to get rid of white spaces

Comment: Both label and input are `display: inline`, per default, so margin and padding bottom or top should not affect them.

Comment: That's why I wrote to make them display: inline-block or block

Comment: Make that kind of layout display flex will inflate the css, it's obvious the issue lies else where. The provided code does not produce the spacing which means there must be other css that's affecting it

Comment: Inflating, with one line of css ? Hahaha
I get it, but for other people ending up here, browsers usually has that white space and it's a solution to get rid of it.